# Most elegant one-liner to generate sqlite INSERTs

Tags: code-challenge, bash, sql

## Challenge

You find yourself in a `bash` terminal, and want to do some simple tests
on `sqlite3`.

So you issue the following command:

```bash
echo "CREATE TABLE T (id INT NON NULL PRIMARY KEY)" | sqlite3 test.db
```

Now you want to insert the first `N` integers (starting from 0, excluding N) into the table `T`.

For convenience, you execute the following

```bash
N=5 # value arbitrary and large, not known for purposes of the challenge
```

Now for the example case of `N == 5`, you would have to execute the following SQL command:

```bash
echo "INSERT INTO T VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4);" | sqlite3 test.db
```

But of course, `N` is large, so you want to come op with a `bash` oneliner
to dynamically generate and execute the SQL statement to insert these values.

---

## Rules

- The result of entering the command string into the presented `bash` teminal session (and pressing enter) should be the modification of `test.db` as described in the challenge.
- You must not leave behind any unintended artifacts on disk (ignoring command histories etc.)
- Any cli tool can be called and considered installed, e.g. `python -c`, `ghci -e`, `awk`, ...
- The final command string must be a **single** line of characters enterable in the `bash` terminal session described above
  (if we want to get technical, the command string cannot contain a byte with value 10  (LF))
- Your command string must be valid UTF-8
- You don't absolutely have to end in `| sqlite3 test.db`, if the tools you are using
  have some built in way to write to `test.db`, that can be used aswell.
  (Although it might not help you that much, see the scoring).
- If you are using tools where it is not obvious how to install them for others (let's just say, if the are not available as a [Debian Package](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages#search_packages)), please add a link on where to get them.

---

## Scoring

Score shall be based on the following metric,
which tries to favor elegant and readable solutions:

- +100 Points by default so we don't have to look at that many negative scores.
- -5 points for every character not in the printable ASCII range (values 32-127, )
- -3 points for every 10 characters above 80  (e.g. 89: -0, 90: -3, 99: -3, 100: -6)
- -2 points for every use of `\`
- -1 point for every use of any of these characters: `` (){}[]'"` ``  (trying to punish nesting here, sorry LISP fans)

The tie breaker are the upvotes, which I hope will respect the spirit of elegant / readable
solutions.

Highest Score wins !

---

Non competing example solution in Haskell to demonstrate Scoring:

```
ghci -e 'import Data.List' -e 'putStr $ "insert into T values" ++ (concat $ intersperse "," $ map (\i -> "(" ++ show i ++ ")") [0..'$N']) ++ ";"' | sqlite3 test.db
```

```
Default:                  = 100
Non Ascii:        0  * -5 =  -0
Length: 164:      8  * -3 = -24
Backslashes:      1  * -2 =  -2
Special Chars:    24 * -1 = -24
--------------------------------
Total Points:                50
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! "Most elegant" challenges aren't really considered a good scoring criterion anymore, and I don't remember off the top of my head, but they might be off-topic. Do you think there's a more objective criterion you could use here, like [tag:code-golf]?

Comment: @Rydwolf Programs
Thanks for the welcome! Shouldn't it be fine since there is an objective number based scoring system?

Comment: So, this is *technically* a [code-challenge], not a pop-con, with an objective scoring criteria: points, with deductions for various things. The pop-con part is only the tiebreaker. I'd suggest, however, rewording the first paragraph under "Scoring" to emphasis that this isn't a pop-con.

Comment: That said, the seemingly arbitrary choice of point deductions may not be popular. For future reference, we recommend using the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) to get feedback on challenge ideas before posting them to main, *especially* for challenges that don't use standard [code-golf] scoring rules

Comment: Also, it might just be more simple to start at 0 points, and get +5/+3/+2/+1 for each, and use lowest score instead

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing: I tried to make the scoring section more clear, Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Yep, that, to me, conveys the objectivity of the scoring system in a much better way :)

Answer (score 4):

## Score 100 (optimal)

```bash
echo seq $1Uxargs MRE sqlite3 testNdb Binsert into t values HEMQIB | tr A-Z !-1Iz-~| bash
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Zc4xCsJAEIXhqzyDhRYRgghWgkJACwUFCxWLTTLRxU2iuxNRES9iE1APldu4YgrBYoapvvnvz0CYbVH2zEFJpjaYDLeiAE6oSTCBRaDsRkNGkCkjzezkSmGvZSL0GTs6N51XzrHbLRcUbjMYOqDuzU9CbwzGMx-_9sTaA5ka0vzxMksfhcrJYOiPp6MBrmCNvrtEzfVGF_d2xaeweuD8ZRpSFFoqQqyzBFylPFaddfE93w)

This is the version below, but encoded so that it contains no literal `()"` characters (and with some whitespace removed, so the final thing fits in under 90 characters)

## Score 96

```bash
seq $1 | xargs -I % sqlite3 test.db "insert into t values (% - 1)"
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZYw9CsJAFISvMgQDsYgQRLCysPMMYrGbfdHFzd--FzHgTWwC6qFyG1cUmxQzTDHfd39qxadh3HDrrNASQiwLoxHlnpQQRGkXGok1sJWgqkM659B4Wyrf40z9PHp1UqTrccvUYpbhhqvyR0a6Q4yJ2VZMXj62OogvynXESGKkyP6maEIxOcoDZVD4uoT8no_96jB85xs)

Gratuitous whitespace, in the spirit of elegance, since it's still well under 90 bytes.